# For loop seems to be running more than necessary in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

```
for(LogProcess process : lo) {
  for(PathInfo info : process.getPathinfolist()) {
    a1.add(info.getFilepath());
  }
}
```

I have this piece of code here. `lo` is an instance of a `LinkedList` of size.

The `LinkedList` is of:

```
public LogProcess(int rev, String auth, String date,
                  List<PathInfo> pathinfolist)
```

Now `PathInfo` is of:

```
public PathInfo(String action,String kind,String filepath)
```

Now my `LinkedList` size is `130`. And that is fine.

But `process.getPathInfoList()` is reading `1657` records from xml. However after the loop when I check the size of `a1` using `a1.size()` it shows `7216` which is impossible. Where am I wrong?

Comment: This question cannot be answered without seeing a complete example of code that produces this behavior (see http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2):

You loop over different process instances which may have a varuing number of path info so not strange to me.

You should display all the code and size of each list

Comment: The size of the first list I printed shows 130,which is correct.It is the second list which seems to be giving very high values.

Answer (score 0):

As given above a1.size() is total number of PathInfo's in all LogProcess objects. as u said there are 130 logprocess objects and getPathInfo reads 1657, but you didn't mention which of logprocess have that many pathinfo's. Does all have same number? I guess you have to provide more details as said above.